# Assign ivars to local variables within a function?

Tags: objective-c, function, local-variables, ivar

Is it recommended to assign an instance variable to a local variable within a function in objective c? If it is used several times, it gives a better overview. Also is it faster performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, it is irrelevant unless you measure otherwise.  And the chances of the performance difference, if any, actually making a difference is negligible.   Depends on how you're are accessing the iVars, though.  Direct or via a method call.   Via a method call will make a difference if you're doing so a zillion times in a tight loop, say, but that is more indicative of a design problem than a local optimization issue.